# Pyopencl module install error

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, compilation, windows-10

I am having trouble installing pyopencl module on Python 2.7. I have already tried on Python 3.4 and 3.5 with no success (kept running into the varstall error)

Now on 2.7 I get the error stdint.h cannot be opened because it does not exist. How does one install this module. I have windows 10 64 bit

Comment: how you tried installing ? using pip ??

Comment: Yes I am using pip

Comment: did u installed mako already ?

Comment: What is mako?     ---------

Answer (score 0):

When i tried Installing it first using PIP i got the error to install [Mako](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Mako/%22Mako%22) . After i installed mako when i tried installing pyopencl it installed fine

**PS ** : Im working on python3.4

Comment: Installed mako and I get the same errors across Python versions 2.7, 3.4, & 3.5

Comment: sorry to hear that. It worked with me so thought it would help you !